# After the modal is closed render the data on a different partial view

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, partial-views

I have reviewed many examples and still have not been able to get this to work.

I am trying to return the data object to display on a different partial view after the modal has been closed without refreshing the page.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateWebOrder", null, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">

            @*//@Html.Partial("_DisplayShipToInfo", Model)*@

            @if (Model.Ship_To_Name == null && Model.WebOrderDetails.Count == 0)
            {
                <div class="pull-left col-lg-1">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" data-modal="" href="/WebOrder/CreateShipTo" id="btnCreate">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                  **<div id="partialDiv">
                     @Html.Partial("_DisplayShipToInfo", Model)
                  </div>**
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Partial("_DisplayShipToInfo", Model)
            }
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6" data-posey-ajax="true" data-posey-target="#DisplayBillToInfo">
            @Html.Partial("_DisplayBillToInfo", Model)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I created a partial view "_AddShipToInfo" for adding the data.

And I have another partial view "_DisplayShipToInfo" for displaying the data.

**The display partial view "_DisplayShipToInfo" contains the following:**

```
@model PoseySqlApp.ViewModels.WebOrderVM

<div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ship_To_Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ship_To_Address_1)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ship_To_Address_2)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ship_To_City_Name)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ship_To_State_Code)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ship_To_Zip_Code)
    </div>
</div>
```

**The controller action is returning the data object.**

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> Create(WebOrderVM webOrderVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            Mapper.CreateMap<WebOrder, WebOrderVM>();

            WebOrder webOrder = Mapper.DynamicMap<WebOrder>(webOrderVM);

            db.WebOrders.Add(webOrder);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(new {webOrder, success = true });
        }

        return Json(webOrderVM, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

How can I get the data object to render the partial view "_DisplayShipTo" from the jquery.

**Jquery**

```
function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    **$("#partialDiv").html(result)**
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Can you clarify why your 'Create' controller method returns 'JsonResult' rather than 'PartialResult'? I have recently achieved similar behaviour by switching from 'Html.BeginForm' to 'Ajax.BeginForm' and then returning a 'PartialResult' if 'this.Request.IsAjaxRequest' == 'true'.

Comment: This should have been ActionResult and not JsonResult

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest approach is to switch to 'Ajax.BeginForm' and then write the 'Create' method in the following manner:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(WebOrderVM webOrderVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<WebOrder, WebOrderVM>();

        WebOrder webOrder = Mapper.DynamicMap<WebOrder>(webOrderVM);

        db.WebOrders.Add(webOrder);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    if (this.Request.IsAjaxRequest)
        return PartialView("~/Views/Orders/Partial/_DisplayShipToInfo.cshtml", webOrderVM);
    else
        return View("OrderPage", webOrderVM);
}
```

The 'Ajax.BeginForm' would be something like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "Create", "WebOrder", null,
    new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "partialDiv",
        OnBegin = function () { /* show progress dialog */ },
        OnComplete = function () { /* hide progress dialog */ }
    }))
{
    ...
    <div id="partialDiv">
        <!-- ajax result rendered here -->
    </div>
    ...
}
```

This works because the 'Ajax.BeginForm' targets '_DisplayShipToInfo' so when the 'POST' returns the rendered 'div' tag will be replaced.

**NOTE:** You must include 'jQuery.unobtrusive-ajax.js' for the 'Ajax.BeginForm' to work.

Comment: Hi karmasponge... I would hate to change this.  I almost have this working.  The problem has to do with the page refreshing.  I just need to refresh the _DisplayShipTo partial view.

Comment: RThomspon, I've updated to better reflect your specific issue

Comment: Hi karmasponge,,, i really thank you for helping me.  Well it works but not how I would like for it to work.  On the main view I have a button.  When the user clicks the button the modal displays the "_AddShipToInfo" partial view.  What I am trying to do is replace the button that the user clicked to display the modal and replace that button with the "_DisplayShipTo" partial view.  The example you gave me display a modal "_DisplayShipTo" partial view.

Comment: After the modal closes.  How can I put the _DisplayShipTo in the same place at the button.   <div id="partialDiv">
                     @Html.Partial("_DisplayShipToInfo", Model)
                  </div>

Comment: Sorry, I meant to update that earlier. Simply change the 'UpdateTargetId' to  'partialDiv', or the 'id' of any element you want, and the 'Ajax.BeginForm' will replace that element with the returned HTML.

Comment: Hi karmasponge... the DisplayShipToInfo is displaying in a modal dialog.  I would like the for the DisplayShipToInfo display on the left side of the format where the original button was clicked.  I am already showing the DisplayBillToInfo on the right side.

Comment: Ok, I totally skipped over that part. I think the simplest thing would be to add an 'OnSuccess' handler to the 'Ajax.BeginForm' and in the handler call '$("#_DisplayShipToInfo").dialog(options)' (assuming your using some sort of javascript library to do it). If you want the dialog to show first then use 'OnBegin' then set the 'UpdateTargetId' to a div inside the dialog (its not clear if you want the content inside or outside the dialog).

Comment: I would like for it be outside the dialog.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the 'partialDiv' that would be updated from 'Ajax' and explicit handlers for showing and hiding the model dialog. I believe that should satisfy your requirements.